# BoxShadow: inset on img tag

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I'm trying to create a embossed effect on an image (like a polaroid). so there should be a box-shadow on the top and the left edge insetted to the picture. But it isn't working... is this a browser problem:

I have created a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PEgBv/25/ to show what i want.

I like it like on the second div box, (where it is working). But on the images, the shadow is only displayed without the `inset` attribute.

Working with chrome14 on linux

[image: screenshot from Chrome14 on linux]

Comment: just tried on win7 with ie9, ff6, chrome14 and safari... also not working!

Comment: I don't know if I'd call it a browser problem.  The images are just being rendered on top of the shadow, so it's not showing up.  You can [tell if you use transparent images](http://jsfiddle.net/LJcWE/)

Comment: If you look at your example closely, you'll see that the text `foo` is rendered on top, as well.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

CSS3 inset shadows don’t work on images, but there is a workaround,

Check here: http://bavotasan.com/2011/adding-inset-shadow-to-image-css3/

Answer (score 3):

The workaround does not work for images with `max-width: 100%;` and `height: auto;` which are often used in fluid designs to make the images scale automatically until they reach their original width. To make the surrounding `<a>` (or whatever element) expand to cover all the content (the image) you need to add display: inline-block; to it, otherwise the shadow will not show as expected.

So, in addition to the styles in the proposed workaround, `display: inline-block;` should be added to the class `.img-shadow`.

Answer (score 2):

It will work if you use the image on a background. So, instead of using img tag, use `background-image: url(source.jpg);` in either css file or style attribute. Box-shadow is rendered on top of the background image.